# Google Cloud Speech API longrunningrecognize only returns name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to convert over an hour audio data to text using Google Cloud Speech API, and I'm using API explorer since it's easy.

The request looks like this.

```
POST https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
  "audio": {
    "uri": "gs://data/audio.flac"
  },
  "config": {
    "encoding": "FLAC",
    "languageCode": "en-US"
  }
}
```

The response look like this.

```
200 
Show headers 
{
  "name": "`numbers`"
}
```

How come it is only returning the name, and not returning the text of the audio?

Answer (score 8):

Just had the same problem.

Found the answer on https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize

> If the request is successful, the server returns a 200 OK HTTP status code and the response in JSON format:

```
{
  "name": "5543203840552489181"
}
```

> where name is the name of the long running operation created for the request.
>   Wait approximately 30 seconds for processing to complete. To retrieve the result of the operation, make a GET request:

```
GET https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YOUR_OPERATION_NAME?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Got my results with:

```
curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/{name}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just checked from my laptop and it works. I'm going to make a simple open source app using this.